# How do I make the clone of the source element disappear on a drag and drop in Google Closure?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I have been tinkering with drag and drop in Google Closure libraries:
http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_fx_DragDropGroup.html

I was wondering how to hide the cloned source element (that follows the cursor around) when the "dragstart" event is fired. Here is my current callback function for the dragstart event. I am sure that it is being called at the right time. However, it is failing at hiding the cloned element.

```
/**
 * Called when drag starts.
 * @param {Event} e The event signaling the start of drag.
 * @private
 */
Foo.prototype.dragStart_ = 
    function(e) {
  goog.style.setOpacity(e.dragSourceItem.element, 0);
  goog.style.showElement(e.dragSourceItem.element, false);
}
```

How do I hide the cloned source element that follows the mouse around? I don't mind hiding the actual drag source element as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event handler for `dragstart` should work if you remove the call to `goog.style.showElement`.

```js
/**
 * Called when drag starts.
 * @param {Event} e The event signaling the start of drag.
 * @private
 */
Foo.prototype.dragStart_ = function(e) {
  goog.style.setOpacity(e.dragSourceItem.element, 0.0);
};
```

See the ***[Drag & Drop Demos](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/index.html)***.

In the demo file *dragdrop.html* the `dragStart(event)` function is defined as follows:

```js
function dragStart(event) {
  goog.style.setOpacity(event.dragSourceItem.element, 0.5);
}
```

Changing the opacity to `0.0` successfully hides both the source element as well as the drag element.

To keep the source element visible and only hide the drag element, you can override `goog.fx.AbstractDragDrop.prototype.createDragElement(sourceElement)` and use CSS to set the opacity of the drag element. For example, in the *dragdrop.html* demo, `button 1` uses a custom drag element styled with the CSS class `foo`. The following CSS hides the `button 1` drag element:

```css
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```